# Android in app donations

Tags: java, android, paypal, google-play, google-play-services

I have searched and found that Google has no feature for in app donations to app developers, only in app purchase of managed goods. So many people are suggesting the use of PayPal but I read a guys post about how he implemented the PayPal donation button in his app and Google removed it from the playstore. I'm just appealing to you great developers for advice. What do I do? Is Google still removing apps cause of this? Cause the post I saw was from 2012. If Google still is, what is the best option then to support know app donations?

Comment: I appreciate your view @commonsware, I just thought I would like get the best answers and advice from here. I'm so sorry for being off topic. You can close it down

Comment: I just read the link. My bad. Totally off topic

Comment: You can implement in-app purchase serving as donation

Comment: Marcin Orlowski, that would mean placing the particular amount you want, but it's supposed to be a donation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking how to make in-app donations in Google Play, and is not a programming question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the Google Play Developer Program Policies, you cannot accept donations or in-app purchases via any other method.

https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

"In-store purchases: Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play **must use Google Play’s payment system**."

"In-app purchases: Developers offering products within a game downloaded from Google Play or providing access to game content **must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment**."

So yes, they will still remove these PayPal apps on Google Play.

You can, however, direct users to a web site that asks for PayPal donations or invites users to join your Patreon.

Comment: How do I do the patreon stuff?

Comment: You sign up as a Creator here https://www.patreon.com/ and then get people to support your project for as little as $1 per month. You use their "private streams" to deliver bonus content to your patrons. The key is to deliver regular, interesting content based on your company's products. Previews, sneak peeks, early access, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I understand now. Anyways, isn't directing users to a PayPal website gonna lead to the removal of the app from the playstore?

Comment: It depends on how you do it. Directing users to a PayPal site asking for donations is fine. Directing users to PayPal where you sell items or applications in violation of the Dev Agreement is different.

Comment: So I can have a button in my app that sends the user to a site (i.e paypal) to make a donation there, and thats perfectly legal as far as google is concerned, they wont ban me ?

Comment: Yes, you can do a link that asks for donations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sorry Im only seeing your answer now. I got no notifaction when you replied. can the button say donate via paypal

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I just had my app rejected because on my website I ask for paypal donations.

Answer (score 14):

I released a CC SA-BY 4.0 application at Google Play. It is totally free, no premium version, no in-app billing stuff, no ads at all.

First I had a direct link to my paypal.me account in the about section of the app. The Play Team then rejected my app because of the direct link.

Then I created a subpage on my website for contribution and donations and linked to that site in the about section of my app. My app was then rejected by the Play Team again.

Screenshot the Play Team sent me showing what's not allowed:

[image: not allowed]

Now that they always reject my app, I removed the link completely, linking only to my website and I hope I am allowed to do so. Then users would have to use the menu of my wordpress website and click the contribute link if they even want to donate.

Thanks to Google for making this so hard and unfair.

I could implement an in-app billing thing with ID in Play Console and my code, but this is what the Google policy says regarding donations:

> Here are some examples of products **not currently supported** by Google Play In-app Billing:
> ...
> One time-payments, including peer-to-peer payments, online auctions, **and donations**.

I know that many devs do it anyway - they use the in-app billing. It's just pure arbitrariness that some devs get their app rejected because of things like that and others don't. But Google is a huge giant without a soul - a small dev like me can only try writing them an e-mail ... and they don't care anyway.

Comment: I sent them an email asking them if I can add a PayPal donation button in my app, they just reply we don't support this future, that's it!!!. But after searching i find that we can add direct payment getaway like stripe I think so. But i still struggle to integrate it in my app without a server.

Comment: Same here. I had implemented a PayPal.me link too. According to your answer I will not try to link to my website for donations. I will remove the donation feature completely...

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, and according to the Google Play Developer Program Policies, one time-payments, including donations, are NOT allowed by Google...

https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/monetization-ads/

> Here are some examples of products **not currently supported** by Google
>   Play In-app Billing:
>
> - Retail merchandise, such as groceries, clothing, housewares, and
>     electronics.
> - Service fees, including taxi and transportation services,
>     cleaning services, food delivery, airfare, and event tickets.
> - One-time membership fees or recurring dues, including gym memberships, loyalty programs, or clubs offering accessories, clothing, or other physical products.
> - **One time-payments, including peer-to-peer payments, online
>     auctions, and donations. Electronic bill payment, including credit
>     card bills, utilities, and cable or telecommunications services.**

Comment: Yes syntax chosen by Google is a little weird... You have to read the page to better understand the slight difference.

Comment: Does it mean I can add a PayPal button to my app?